# Magento 1.9 product list with AJAX

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I'd like to list the products using AJAX. I know I need to create a module, but I cannot do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Infinity scroll to show the product list in ajax

https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento-InfiniteScroll